# Create react app with npx that uses classes and not hooks

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, react-hooks

I want to use `npx create-react-app .` to generate a new react app but I want the version to be changed so that it generates with class structures and not the new hook structure.

I've tried changing the version of `react` and `React-DOM` in the package.json and running `npm i` but it doesn't overwrite the old app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the boilerplate App.js created doesn't use hooks at all, but it does use functional components. Just replace it to something of the likes:

#### Functional Component Version:

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    < ...this will go inside the render() method... >
  );
}
```

#### Class Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (< ... >)
  }
}
```

Don't forget the `{ Component }` import, or alternatively use `extends React.Component`.

Answer (score 0):

I did use npx  create-react-app yesterday and the App generated was class based.

Solution 1)
 Try running npx create-react-app again

Solution 2)
 If you run npx create react-app and it still generate hook based app for you.  You can delete the hook based components and do your own class based component.  Moreover,  CRA provides the App.js which you can easily change to your need.  If you are using Vscode there is react extension that can easily help out with creating React class component.

Comment: The latest version of `create-react-app` uses functional components, not sure if it was updated in V2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--scripts-version {script version}` after create-react-app. 
Example: `create-react-app --scripts-version 1.1.5`

it will create the scripts with classes instead of functions.

See all script versions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts)